# Coredata migration is really needed?

Tags: core-data, swift2, xcode7, core-data-migration

I have a SQLite database with two columns it is bundled in the app. There is no write or save interaction in the database, it is fixed and read only. I read some documents and tutorials about the lightweight/manual migration all make it clear that you have to save the user data when migrating, that is not my case I don't need to save user data, I will deploy a new app version with a new database. I want to add two new attributes to my database and use in the app. Why I have to migrate? Why can't I just delete the old three files of SQLite database and add the new one and use the new attributes as needed. So I tried and did not work, anyone here to give me the steps to make the app to recognize the new database?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the way to delete the SQL database files is the right way.

But you have to do that **before** the Core Data stack is going to be initialized.

Comment: I am not very familiar with this procedure do you have any link or tutorial to help me with this? thanks for your time

Comment: In the Core Data stack part there is a property `applicationDocumentsDirectory` to get the URL of the dictionary where the data store is located. Implement `applicationWillFinishLaunching` in `AppDelegate` , in this method make a version check and use that code to get the dictionary and delete all files starting with the name of the data store using `NSFileManager`.

Comment: what I did was to delete the database, added the new one, and add two new attributes, but I got many error messages ;(

Comment: The point is that the data model and the store file are related. At the moment the Core Data stack is initialized the software checks if both files match. On failure you get an error message about that. But if you delete and create a new data store file matching the new model **before** the stack is initialized the consistency check succeeds.

Comment: I am not at home, I will try what you said and give you an update asap. In the meanwhile I will try to find the steps to do it.

Comment: @Manolo, just before `addPersistentStoreWithType` use the newer api `[psc destroyPersistentStoreAtURL:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] withType:NSSQLiteStoreType options:options error:&error];`

Comment: @Khundragpan is it the same as reset the simulator so it destroys all data in the app folder in the Mac or delete the app from the device?

Comment: @Manolo No, it will just delete the sqlite store, previously this was done using `NSFileManager` watch WWDC video [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-220/) at 09:10

Comment: Great I Will Watch the video